# Interpreting a Crash Log Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, crash-reports

I'm trying to interpret this crash log below, but I'm not sure if I understand it correctly. `objc_msgSend()` means that I'm sending a message to something that's already dealloced. So basically the data source disappears before the tableview can draw its cells?

How can I find the cause of this problem? I've tried using the `atos` tool to find the location of the crash by the hex it returns, but no avail.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000020
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:


Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x93f89ed7 objc_msgSend + 23
1   com.apple.AppKit                0x936143ea -[NSTableView preparedCellAtColumn:row:] + 335
2   com.apple.AppKit                0x9362e8bc -[NSTableView _drawContentsAtRow:column:withCellFrame:] + 56
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x9362d92a -[NSTableView drawRow:clipRect:] + 1131
4   com.apple.AppKit                0x9362d362 -[NSTableView drawRowIndexes:clipRect:] + 360
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x9362bd3b -[NSTableView drawRect:] + 1144
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x936218fd -[NSView _drawRect:clip:] + 3721
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x9361efc9 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 2217
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x9361f95c -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4668
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x9361f95c -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4668
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x9361f95c -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4668
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x9361f95c -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4668
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x9361e55b -[NSThemeFrame _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 265
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x9361aea2 -[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:] + 3309
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x9357ba57 -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 818
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x93544d40 -[NSWindow displayIfNeeded] + 204
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x9357628a _handleWindowNeedsDisplay + 696
17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x94f0ae02 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 1186
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x94ec6d8d __CFRunLoopRun + 557
19  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x94ec6464 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
20  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x94ec6291 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
21  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x94188004 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 392
22  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x94187cf7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 158
23  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x94187c40 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 81
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x9354c78d _DPSNextEvent + 847
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x9354bfce -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 156
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x9350e247 -[NSApplication run] + 821
27  com.apple.AppKit                0x935062d9 NSApplicationMain + 574
28  ...yapp.com 0x00003032 0x1000 + 8242
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the classic symptom of a memory management error.  `NSTableView` is attempting to access some piece of data (perhaps an object value or an item or something?) that has been deallocated, but that the tableview still references.

There are a couple ways to solve this:

- Run the static analyzer on your code.  This will find any obvious leaks
- Run your code using Instruments, specifically with the Zombies tool turned on.  That will keep track of when you try to send a message to an object that's already been deallocated.  It will also include *tons* of useful information, like when and where the object was created, when and where it was retained, released, and autoreleased, and finally where it was deallocated.

Comment: Here's the problem: It only crashes on certain machines, and that excludes mine. The arrays that power the tableview are protected in a way that when the tableview calls `objectValueForTableColumn:` and it detects that the array is nil, it creates it prior to passing it to the tableview. I dont release them anywhere except in `dealloc`.

Comment: I doubt it was the object value that was overreleased—more probably the data source itself.

Answer (score 3):

Greg Parker is an engineer fir the Objective-C runtime. His blog post on interpreting crashes in objc_msgSend is essentially the definitive source: http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2008/09/22/objc_explain_So_you_crashed_in_objc_msgSend.html.

Short answer: you have a memory corrupting bug.